# BottomSheetScaffold M3 sheetContent not updated according to states

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, material3

I am building an app using BottomSheetScaffold in Jetpack Compose with Material3. However, I'm facing an issue where the sheetContent does not update after the states have changed.

Initially, I suspected that the states were not being updated from the viewModel. However, after conducting a thorough investigation, I discovered that the states are indeed updating correctly. This was confirmed by printing log statements, which clearly showed that the states are being updated every time.

However, I encountered a peculiar issue where the sheetContent or other parameters of BottomSheetScaffold do not receive real-time updates and recomposition. Only the parentheses within BottomSheetScaffold are able to reflect the changes and trigger recomposition.

```
val data by remember { mutableStateOf(mainViewModel.data) }


BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetPeekHeight = 60.dp,
        sheetContent = {
          Logger.d("data1: $data")//only triggered at the first time launch
          BottomSheetInnerContent(data)
        },
    ) {
       Logger.d("data2: $data")//triggered every time when data updated
    
       //other Composable works fine here
       @Composable 
       fun BottomSheetOuterContent() {
       .....

       }

    
}
```

My state variable from ViewModel looks like this.

```
var data = mutableListOf<Data>()
```

If anyone has encountered a similar issue or knows how to resolve it, I would greatly appreciate your insights. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you add your viewmodel state's code as well ?

Comment: Sure, I updated my questions already.

Comment: You are creating a state from the list in the ViewModel. How does the list get updated? and how does that in turn update the state? You may have to use flow to store the list in the ViewModel and collect it in the Composable to reflect the changes to the list.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a reactive data stream like StateFlow or MutableStateOf or in your case MutableStateListOf for holding your ui state in your viewModel instead of creating your state in your composable. Then you should observe these reactive streams from your composable like following:

---

in your ViewModel :

```kotlin
    //declare your state 
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(listOf<Data>())
    val state = _state.asStateFlow()

    ...

    //update it
    private fun fetchData() {
         ...

        _state.value = dataList
    }
```

---

**in your composable**:

```kotlin
    //observe your state and pass it to where it is needed
    val state by viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
```

I can't say for sure that this is the problem but, this is the recommended way to do this anyway.